# How to encode byte array to Base 63 string with custom charset in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, encode

I need to encode byte array to Base63 string in Java (notice, `java.util.Base64` implements Base64 and not Base63).
I need to be able to use custom charset:

```
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','_'
```

I.e. something like:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3};
String base63String = Base63.encode(byteArray);
byte[] decodedByteArray = Base63.decode(base63String);
assert java.util.Arrays.equals(byteArray, decodedByteArray);
```

Comment: Why? Is this some kind of exercise?

Comment: Never heard of a "Base 63" encoding and Java certainly doesn't have a standard encoder / decoder for such an encoding. That means that you have to write your own implementation.

Comment: No, it's actually not exercise. Currently we use Base58 for some data encoding but in some situations the overhead of base58 doesn't work for us. base64 certainly works as it has really small overhead (33-36%) but it uses just 1 more unnecessary character which we can't use. Thus, we thought to find more effective encoding which will work (Base63 would be perfect but it's not a standard).

Comment: Basically, we can use all characters which are allowed as names for Java variables. Unfortunately, Java variables allow only 63 characters to be used for naming

Comment: _Unfortunately, Java variables allow only 63 characters to be used for naming_ not exactly. From the ASCII character set (Unicode code points below 128) Java also allows to use the `$` character in identifiers, but your list doesn't include it. And to be precise: Java allows a wide range of Unicode characters within identifiers (see the [JLS Chapter 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8))

Comment: Ah right. Sorry for confusion. Still the provider supports 63 characters only

Comment: I.e. in my situations I can use only alpha-numeric characters and underscores

Comment: Was able to find a solution of Base58 and modify it to Base63 (actually any base).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was searching for different implementations and tried to change them to `Base63`. I found `Base58` implementation [here](https://github.com/multiformats/java-multibase/blob/master/src/main/java/io/ipfs/multibase/Base58.java). I was able to slightly modify that code to use custom base (in my situation it's Base-63).
The original author isn't me and I didn't investigate the code thoroughly, thus use it at your own risk.

```
public class CustomBase {
    private final char[] alphabet;
    private final int divisor;
    private final char encodedZero;
    private final int[] indexes;

    public CustomBase(char[] alphabet){
        this.alphabet = alphabet;
        this.divisor = alphabet.length;
        this.encodedZero = alphabet[0];
        this.indexes = new int[128];
        Arrays.fill(indexes, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            char alphabetChar = alphabet[i];
            if(alphabetChar >= indexes.length){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("All chars should be under 128 but there was a char "+alphabetChar);
            }
            if(indexes[alphabet[i]] != -1){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate char found in the alphabet "+alphabetChar);
            }
            indexes[alphabet[i]] = i;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encodes the given bytes as a baseX string (no checksum is appended).
     *
     * @param input the bytes to encode
     * @return the baseX-encoded string
     */
    public String encode(byte[] input) {
        if (input.length == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        // Count leading zeros.
        int zeros = 0;
        while (zeros < input.length && input[zeros] == 0) {
            ++zeros;
        }
        // Convert base-256 digits to base-X digits (plus conversion to ASCII characters)
        input = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length); // since we modify it in-place
        char[] encoded = new char[input.length * 2]; // upper bound
        int outputStart = encoded.length;
        for (int inputStart = zeros; inputStart < input.length; ) {
            encoded[--outputStart] = alphabet[divmod(input, inputStart, 256, divisor)];
            if (input[inputStart] == 0) {
                ++inputStart; // optimization - skip leading zeros
            }
        }
        // Preserve exactly as many leading encoded zeros in output as there were leading zeros in input.
        while (outputStart < encoded.length && encoded[outputStart] == encodedZero) {
            ++outputStart;
        }
        while (--zeros >= 0) {
            encoded[--outputStart] = encodedZero;
        }
        // Return encoded string (including encoded leading zeros).
        return new String(encoded, outputStart, encoded.length - outputStart);
    }

    /**
     * Decodes the given baseX string into the original data bytes.
     *
     * @param input the baseX-encoded string to decode
     * @return the decoded data bytes
     */
    public byte[] decode(String input) {
        if (input.length() == 0) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
        // Convert the baseX-encoded ASCII chars to a baseX byte sequence (baseX digits).
        byte[] inputX = new byte[input.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            int digit = c < 128 ? indexes[c] : -1;
            if (digit < 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("InvalidCharacter in base "+divisor);
            }
            inputX[i] = (byte) digit;
        }
        // Count leading zeros.
        int zeros = 0;
        while (zeros < inputX.length && inputX[zeros] == 0) {
            ++zeros;
        }
        // Convert base-X digits to base-256 digits.
        byte[] decoded = new byte[input.length()];
        int outputStart = decoded.length;
        for (int inputStart = zeros; inputStart < inputX.length; ) {
            decoded[--outputStart] = divmod(inputX, inputStart, divisor, 256);
            if (inputX[inputStart] == 0) {
                ++inputStart; // optimization - skip leading zeros
            }
        }
        // Ignore extra leading zeroes that were added during the calculation.
        while (outputStart < decoded.length && decoded[outputStart] == 0) {
            ++outputStart;
        }
        // Return decoded data (including original number of leading zeros).
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(decoded, outputStart - zeros, decoded.length);
    }

    /**
     * Divides a number, represented as an array of bytes each containing a single digit
     * in the specified base, by the given divisor. The given number is modified in-place
     * to contain the quotient, and the return value is the remainder.
     *
     * @param number the number to divide
     * @param firstDigit the index within the array of the first non-zero digit
     *        (this is used for optimization by skipping the leading zeros)
     * @param base the base in which the number's digits are represented (up to 256)
     * @param divisor the number to divide by (up to 256)
     * @return the remainder of the division operation
     */
    private static byte divmod(byte[] number, int firstDigit, int base, int divisor) {
        // this is just long division which accounts for the base of the input digits
        int remainder = 0;
        for (int i = firstDigit; i < number.length; i++) {
            int digit = (int) number[i] & 0xFF;
            int temp = remainder * base + digit;
            number[i] = (byte) (temp / divisor);
            remainder = temp % divisor;
        }
        return (byte) remainder;
    }
}
```

The usage example:

```
public static final char[] ALPHABET = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','_'};
private static final CustomBase BASE_63 = new CustomBase(ALPHABET);

public void testEncoding(){
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3};
    String base63String = BASE_63.encode(byteArray);
    byte[] decodedByteArray = BASE_63.decode(base63String);
    assert java.util.Arrays.equals(byteArray, decodedByteArray);
}
```

The above code shows slightly better compression in some situations when compared to Base58 original code if we use it with Base63 alphabet. That said, in most cases it gives the same or similar compression as Base58.

Comparison:

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 57]

This byte array will be encoded in 25 characters when Base58 is used but in 24 characters when Base63 is used. 

[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -66, -5, -17, -66, -5, -17, -66, -5]

the above bytes will be encoded in 61 characters when we use Base58 and in 59 characters when we use Base63.
```

Conclusion: The above Base63 implementation gives small improvements to Base58 in some situations and no improvements in many other situations. Probably, the main advantage of using `CustomBase` implementation is the ability to use your own character set.

Comment: Works pretty nicely, although I should note that it fails for bases less than 16. I think the `new char[input.length * 2]; // upper bound` line ends up picking too low of an upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) project offers [`Base16`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base16.html), [`Base32`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32.html) and [`Base64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) encoders and decoders.

These all inherit from a [`BaseNCodec`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.html) class that provides a basis for writing arbitrary-base encoder/decoder classes. Unfortunately, there's not much documentation for implementing a custom subclass, but the source code for the existing implementations can be instructive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on BaseNCodec. I will try to check that if it can be used for custom base. Nevertheless, I posted solution with Base63 encoding below. (I tested it with some examples but didn't do proper deep testing, thus can't be sure it works as expected).